# C++1y auto function type deduction

Tags: c++, auto, c++14

Consider following:

```
auto list = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 4);

/// Work like a charm
template <class T>
auto test1(T &&brush) -> decltype(std::get<0>( std::forward<T>(brush) )) {
    return std::get<0>( std::forward<T>(brush) );
}


/// And now - C++14 feature
/// fail to compile - return value(temporary), instead of l-reference
template <class T>
auto test2(T &&brush) {
    return std::get<0>( std::forward<T>(brush) );
}

int main()
{
    auto &t1 = test1(list);
    auto &t2 = test2(list);        
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/816dea1a0ed3e9ee

Both, gcc and clang throw error:

```
main.cpp:26:11: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'int'
    auto &t2 = test2(list);        
          ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Shouldn't it work like with *decltype*? Why difference?

---

**UPDATED**

Wouldn't it be, in case with `std::get`, be equivalent to this? (I work with gcc 4.8)

```
template <class T>
auto&& test2(T &&brush) {
    return std::get<0>( std::forward<T>(brush) );
}
```

Comment: `test1` and `test2` return type are `int`, and you can't bind it to `int&`. try `auto && t1` or `auto t1` or `auto const & t1`

Comment: @BryanChen Why I can't have reference to int value?

Comment: @BryanChen Return type of `test1` is `int&`. `decltype` preserves the reference. Thats the difference between `decltype(auto)` and `auto`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`auto` only deduces the object type, meaning the the value-category of the object returned is not part of the return type.

Using the `auto` placeholder, type of the return statement is deduced by rules of template argument deduction:

> `§ 7.1.6.4/7` `auto specificer`  `[dcl.spec.auto]`
>
> > If the placeholder is the auto *type-speciﬁer*, the deduced type is determined using the rules for template argument deduction.

`decltype(auto)` on the other hand uses deduction as if by `decltype()`:

> `§ 7.1.6.4/7` `auto specificer`  `[dcl.spec.auto]`
>
> > If the placeholder is the `decltype(auto)` *type-speciﬁer*, the declared type of the variable or return type of the function shall be the placeholder alone. The type deduced for the variable or return type is determined as described in `7.1.6.2`, as though the initializer had been the operand of the `decltype`.

So for perfect-forwarding return types, this is what you should use. Here's how it looks:

```
template <class T>
decltype(auto) test2(T &&brush) {
    return std::get<0>(std::forward<T>(brush));
}
```

As a result, the return type will be an rvalue/lvaue-reference depending on the deduced type of `brush`.

I tested the above on Coliru, and it seems that `g++ 4.8` can't compile the above code yet, though using [`clang++`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96677bd195b4dbfb) it compiles fine.

Comment: It's harder and harder to answer those C++14 questions before someone else does.... Has C++ jumped the shark?

Comment: My copy of GCC 4.9 has no trouble with your code, but using a trailing return to say `auto` seems a little excessive.

Comment: +1 but do you really need to use trailing return types to say `decltype(auto)`?

Comment: It seems it is possible without trailing return http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/607a16b9d99afa71

Comment: @tower120 You're asking if the `decltype(auto)` example is equivalent to `auto&&`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Maybe :)... I mean, in this particular case, `std::get` always return & or &&, so if I add && to auto it will automaticaly deducted to correct reference. Right?

Comment: @tower120 `std::get` always returns a reference type, so `auto&&` will perform reference-collapsing to deduce it to the correct lvalue/rvalue reference. If you used `decltype(auto)` you would get the same results in this case, but they are not equivalent in other cases (like when returning a non-reference type, the deduced type will not be a reference).

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't it work like with decltype? Why difference?

It should work like `decltype`, but `auto` doesn't work exactly like `decltype` in other cases, and they didn't want to make `auto` inconsistent.

Instead, C++1y introduces new syntax `decltype(auto)` for the idiomatic deduced function return type.

Comment: @tower120 [Here](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2013/07/when-decltype-meets-auto.html) is a blog post from Scott Meyers. I seem to recall a more in-depth discussion from him.